# Is this tag too [abstract]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

I don't see the need to have both [abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract) and [abstract-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-class). I think the former could be synonymized with the latter. It could be argued that [abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract) would be needed for when one has a question about specifically abstract methods. However in languages I'm familiar with, abstract methods are going to be part of an abstract class, so they could be viewed as a feature of an abstract-class.

Further, questions are being tagged abstract because they involve abstract data types, are abstract questions, deal with abstraction, etc. The tags provides much opportunity for mistagging, and little specificity beyond others.

Comment: Man, I was thinking this was a burnination request... so disillusioned it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

Given the current state of questions with [abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract), it and [abstract-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-class) should *not* be brought together.

`abstract` is a keyword, and *many* of the questions in that tag deal with the uses of that keyword.  They also deal with concepts of polymorphism and other things, which makes me think that the questions in [abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract) need to be reviewed, and have the tag possibly burninated.